# d3.js window scaling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a forced directed graph with hundreds of nodes and links but the window size is too small that it cannot display all the nodes (links). I have to scroll down or up in the chrome browser to see all the data. Below is my code for the window, how to scale all the data to fit in the current window

```
        var width = 2400;
        var height = 1500;
        var color = d3.scale.category20c();

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not recommended to actively resize your user's window, you could do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

A better way to accommodate your nodes is to make the `div` containing your `svg` element scrollable (try to put the `style` attributes into a separate CSS file):

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;">
    <svg><!-- your contents --></svg>
</div>
```

**Or**

Resize your `svg` and all its elements (e.g. your nodes) according to the size of current window. That would be another story to tell.